# Elm 0.19: How to obtain request body when receiving BadStatus with elm/http 2.0.0

Tags: http, elm

elm/http 1.0.0 defined `Http.Error` as

```
type Error
    = BadUrl String
    | Timeout
    | NetworkError
    | BadStatus (Response String)
    | BadPayload String (Response String)
```

but 2.0.0 changed it to

```
type Error
    = BadUrl String
    | Timeout
    | NetworkError
    | BadStatus Int
    | BadBody String
```

When receiving `BadStatus` I cannot obtain the body of the request, only the status code. In the [docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#expectStringResponse) Evan suggests a solution for this, but I don't understand how to make it work.

If we defined our own `expectJson` similar to

```
expectJson : (Result Http.Error a -> msg) -> D.Decoder a -> Expect msg
expectJson toMsg decoder =
  expectStringResponse toMsg <|
    \response ->
      case response of
        Http.BadStatus_ metadata body ->
          Err (Http.BadStatus metadata.statusCode)
        ...
```

Then we have access to the metadata and body, but how do I use them? Should I define my own `myBadStatus` and return that instead?

```
Http.BadStatus_ metadata body ->
  Err (myBadStatus metadata.statusCode body)
```

Would this work?

What I need is to convert the following code:

```
myErrorMessage : Http.Error -> String
myErrorMessage error =
    case error of
        Http.BadStatus response ->
            case Decode.decodeString myErrorDecoder response.body of
                Ok err ->
                    err.message
                Err e ->
                    "Failed to parse JSON response."
        ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: I discovered this lib https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/jzxhuang/http-extras/1.0.0/ that seems to use the same approach I suggested in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit 22/4/2019:** I updated this answer for version 2.0+ of http-extras which has some API changes. Thanks to Berend de Boer for pointing this out!

The answer below gives a solution using a package I wrote (as per request), but you don't have to use the package! I wrote an [entire article](https://medium.com/@jzxhuang/going-beyond-200-ok-a-guide-to-detailed-http-responses-in-elm-6ddd02322e) on how to extract detailed information from an HTTP response, it includes multiple Ellie examples that don't require the package, as well as an example that uses the package.

---

As Francesco mentioned, I created a package for exactly this purpose, using a similar approach described in the question: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/jzxhuang/http-extras/latest/.

Specifically, the module to use `Http.Detailed`. It defines an Error type that keeps the original body around on error:

```
type Error body
    = BadUrl String
    | Timeout
    | NetworkError
    | BadStatus Metadata body Int
    | BadBody Metadata body String
```

Make a request like so:

```
type Msg
    = MyAPIResponse (Result (Http.Detailed.Error String) ( Http.Metadata, String ))

sendRequest : Cmd Msg
sendRequest =
    Http.get
        { url = "/myapi"
        , expect = Http.Detailed.expectString MyAPIResponse
```

In your update, handle the result including decoding the body when it is BadStatus:

```
update msg model =
    case msg of
        MyAPIResponse httpResponse ->
            case httpResponse of
                Ok ( metadata, respBody ) ->
                    -- Do something with the metadata if you need! i.e. access a header

                Err error ->
                    case error of
                        Http.Detailed.BadStatus metadata body statusCode ->
                            -- Try to decode the body the body here...

                        ...

        ...
```

Thanks the Francisco for reaching out to me about this, hopefully this answer helps anyone who faces the same problem as OP.

Comment: For people looking at this answer, note that it does not compile, and differs from the current API. You want to read the docs itself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I've updated the answer appropriately.